# Integrating histogram and density curve, with one axis for frequency and the other for density

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I'm using the `hist()` and `lines()` functions to create a histogram with a density overlay and would like to have a `y-axis` that shows frequency instead of density.

Is there any way to do this using `hist()` and without using `ggplot`? It would even be better to have the frequency axis as a second y-axis on the right. Here is my code:

```
g <- rnorm(2000,5,1)
h<-hist(g, breaks=50, col="bisque",     
        border="black",ylab="Frequeny",yaxt='n',
        main="Title",xlab=paste0("Cr","(mg/dL)"),prob=TRUE) 
Axis(side=2, at=seq(0, 200, by=20))
lines(density(g),col="dimgray") #For Overlay
```

Setting `prob = FALSE` doesn't help since then lines doesn't work for the density overlay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's first generate the data and `hist` object:

```
set.seed(0)  ## added for reproducibility
g <- rnorm(2000, 5, 1)
h <- hist(g, breaks = 50, plot = FALSE)
```

I have temporally suppressed plotting by `plot = FALSE`.

The issue is, we want to have two y-axes:

- the one on the left shows counts / frequencies;
- the one on the right shows density.

Basically we add tick-marks at density values on both axes, but

- display corresponding counts / frequencies on the left one;
- display density values on the right one.

The density value in `hist` object is `h$density`. For pretty graph, we apply
`pretty()` to get tick-marks positions:

```
pos <- pretty(h$density, n = 5)
# [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6
```

To find the corresponding counts at `pos`, we do:

```
freq <- round(pos * length(g) * with(h, breaks[2] - breaks[1]))
# [1]   0  20  40  60  80 100 120
```

The `round()` used here is just to ensure that the digits introduced by finite precision computation are dropped, so that we end up with integers.

Now we are ready to produce our integrated histogram. Remember to increase the right margin to reserve some space for axis name of the right axis. In the following we set right margin as same as left margin.

```
new.mai <- old.mai <- par("mai")
new.mai[4] <- old.mai[2]
par(mai = new.mai)

graphics:::plot.histogram(h, freq = FALSE, col="bisque", main="Integrated Histogram",
                          xlab = paste0("Cr","(mg/dL)"), ylab="Frequeny",
                          border="black", yaxt='n')
Axis(side = 2, at = pos, labels = freq)
Axis(side = 4, at = pos, labels = pos)
mtext("Density", side = 4, line = 3)
lines(density(g), col="dimgray")

par(mai = old.mai)
```

Note how I used `graphics:::plot.histogram` to plot a `hist` object, and `mtext` to add text on margin. Read `?plot.histogram` and `?mtext` for more.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zheyuan Li! This works perfectly and I don't have to stop using hist().

Comment: Zheyuan Li, yes this is very cool! I wish I could upvote your answer!